# Where I can find wubi?

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, wubi

I used ubuntu in my previous laptop for some years now. I installed it via wubi. Recently I bought a new laptop and I want to do the same thing. Although I used ubuntu almost exclussively, for some reason I DON'T want to make a partition in my new laptop. I only want to install it like I did in my previous one.
   So, I installed it in my previous laptop about three or four years ago (it was ubuntu 12.04 back then or maybe an older version). I remember that I dowloaded a small .exe from the ubuntu page (about 2mb if I remember correctly). When I ran it, a window opened and asked me how much space do I want to dedicate to ubuntu, my user name and a password. Now I cannot find it anywhere. I downloaded the 14.04.2 version from here: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop and I created a virtual cd with deamon. I found the wubi.exe in that and I executed it, but it says that I should restart my computer. It is not like the previous time that it installed ubuntu inside windows. Should I do it? Is it the same, or it will do a partition? I found an older version of wubi somewhere (for 9.04). If I use that one, will I be able to update later to 14.04 from inside ubuntu? I forgot to mention that my new computer (as my previous one) runs windows7 and not 8 (I know that wubi doesn't work with win8). 
   Thank you very much!

Comment: wubi is not supported in 14.04.

Comment: So,, should I install an older version? I had 12.04 in my previous one. If I install the 9.04 that I found can I update it to 12.04?

Comment: 9.04 had reached its EOL years ago. IF you want to still install Ubuntu 'inside' windows, use virtualbox or vmware etc. otherwise make a live USB and install alongside windows.

Comment: Why not install Ubuntu a normal way without wubi?

Comment: Yes, I would really like that (I did that to my previous computer) but I don't know for how long I will keep this one. I think that in a few months I will pass it to my girlfriend and she really doesn't like linux.

Answer (score 0):

Wubi is depreciated. The main function of wubi shipped in 14.04+ is to be a "cd autolauncher" that says "You needto reboot, to try ubuntu!" or something. But when you copy the wubi.exe off the cd, it will launch and offer Wubi based installation on BIOS machine (there is no guarantee with UEFI devices).

In addition, from [Wubi Guide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide):

> Wubi is an officially supported installer for Windows XP, Vista and 7
>   only. Wubi does not work with Windows 8 default boot-loader.
>   Thus at this point Wubi would not work on a new Windows 8 machine. You
>   would be able to install, but not reboot into Ubuntu.
>
> If you upgraded to Windows 8 and are using BIOS firmware, Wubi does
>   work, but do not enable hybrid-sleep on Windows 8.

Note that this applies to Windows 10 also.

To install Ubuntu, burn the iso to a DVD/USB and install from it.

Comment: Oh, thank you! I will try to copy wubi from cd and I will try it out! I will tell you how that went.

Comment: I tried it and something interesting happened. It rebooted, installed the ubuntu and rebooted again. In the selection screen I selected Ubuntu and when it started it said that there were some errors in some files. I pressed skip and then it oped a kernel without grafical elements. I could use the kernel normally, but there were no grafical elements, so I shut it down and rebooted. I selected ubuntu again, and it was the same. Any suggestions?